# How to reference a file in an AWS CodeDeploy package at execution?

Tags: windows, powershell, aws-code-deploy

I want to include a database upgrade script in my AWS CodeDeploy package, but I don't see how to specify a path to it.

I'm successfully triggering PowerShell scripts, and I have one that calls sqlcmd.exe and I want to pass sqlcmd a script to run.

When I print out the current working directory with Get-Location it shows `C:\Windows\system32`. So it seems the only way I would be able to reference it would be to know the current package path.

Is there a way to determine the current current package path within a deployment script?

**Edit - My setup**

[image]

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: .\source
    destination: C:\inetpub\gentest.vanhookservice.com\dev
hooks:
    BeforeInstall:
        - location: .\scripts\db-backup-test.ps1
          timeout: 6000
        - location: .\scripts\code-backup-gentest.ps1
          timeout: 6000
          runas: Administrator
        - location: .\scripts\db-upgrade-test.ps1
          timeout: 6000
```

the `db-upgrade-test.ps1`:

```
# Fail on all errors
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Are you running in 32-bit mode?
#   (\SysWOW64\ = 32-bit mode)

if ($PSHOME -like "*SysWOW64*")
{
  Write-Warning "Restarting this script under 64-bit Windows PowerShell."

  # Restart this script under 64-bit Windows PowerShell.
  #   (\SysNative\ redirects to \System32\ for 64-bit mode)

  & (Join-Path ($PSHOME -replace "SysWOW64", "SysNative") powershell.exe) -File `
    (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $MyInvocation.MyCommand) @args

  # Exit 32-bit script.

  Exit $LastExitCode
}

echo "Upgrading test database..."
sqlcmd.exe -S vhs-awsdev-sql1 -d JobManagerDev -i ..\database\upgrade.sql
# Test if the sqlcmd.exe command exited with a success or error condition
if ($? -eq "False")
{
   throw "sqlcmd.exe failed with exit code $LastExitCode"
}
echo "Test database upgrade complete."
```

The problem is the `..\database\upgrade.sql` reference. I also tried `.\database\upgrade.sql` because that's how the scripts are referenced in `appspec.yml`, but the real problem is the current working directory is actually `C:\Windows\system32`

Comment: I just realized that I'm probably staring at the solution, with the `$PSScriptRoot` used in the 64bit logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$PSScriptRoot` used in the 64bit logic is what I wanted.

The current database upgrade script looks like this:

```
# Fail on all errors
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# Are you running in 32-bit mode?
#   (\SysWOW64\ = 32-bit mode)

if ($PSHOME -like "*SysWOW64*")
{
  Write-Warning "Restarting this script under 64-bit Windows PowerShell."

  # Restart this script under 64-bit Windows PowerShell.
  #   (\SysNative\ redirects to \System32\ for 64-bit mode)

  & (Join-Path ($PSHOME -replace "SysWOW64", "SysNative") powershell.exe) -File `
    (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $MyInvocation.MyCommand) @args

  # Exit 32-bit script.

  Exit $LastExitCode
}

echo "Upgrading production database..."
echo "PSScriptRoot: $PSScriptRoot"
sqlcmd.exe -S vhs-sql1 -d JobManager -i "$PSScriptRoot\..\database\upgrade.sql"
# Test if the sqlcmd.exe command exited with a success or error condition
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)
{
    throw "sqlcmd.exe failed to run, exiting with the code $LastExitCode"
}
echo "Production database upgrade complete."
```

Note the updated sqlcmd.exe line

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your script in the root of your source and specify as follows:

```
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
  - source: \index.html
    destination: c:\inetpub\wwwroot
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: \before-install.bat        # <====== script in source dir root
      timeout: 900
```

Details here:

[1] Step 2: Configure Your Source Content to Deploy to the Windows Server Amazon EC2 Instance  - Add an Application Specification File  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/tutorials-windows-configure-content.html#tutorials-windows-configure-content-add-appspec-file

Comment: My problem isn't running scripts. I'm triggering scripts just fine. I want to have a script file (PowerShell) that references a second script file (SQL)

Comment: I just added sample files of what I'm using to the question